# Why does this simple PDO prepared statement won't work?

Tags: php, pdo, mariadb, prepared-statement

```
$stmt =$dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM config WHERE group=:group AND name=:name');
$stmt->bindParam(':group',$group, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':name',$name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Gives exception:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
version for the right syntax to use near 'group=? AND name=?' at line 1
```

Tried to put the parameters in the execute function, same message.

PDO options i've set are:

```
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=> PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE,
```

Answer (score 1):

`group` is a [reserved word](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/reserved-words/) and can't be used as an [identifier](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/identifier-names/) without back-ticks in MariaDB:

```
SELECT * FROM `config` WHERE `group`= :group AND `name` = :name
```

Comment: This worked for me. Perhaps I should name my columns in my native language to avoid this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

`group`  is a keyword in SQL. You may not used it as a column name without quoting it. In MySQL, things like column names are quoted with back-ticks, i.e. :

```
$stmt =$dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM config WHERE `group` = :group AND `name` = :name');
```